# No route matches, missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

I have one model, "asignacion" and, when an object is created, if it doesn't pass the validations, I want the form to show again with the error list, as usual.

```
def create
    @asignacion = AsignacionDiet.new(asignacion_params)
    if @asignacion.save
      UserMailer.aviso_dieta_asignada(@asignacion.user.email, @asignacion.diet).deliver_now

      flash[:success] = t(:dieta_asignada)
      redirect_to alumnos_path
    else
      @diets = current_user.dietas_visibles
      @diets = @diets.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
      render :new, id: @asignacion.user_id
    end
  end
```

The problem is that when @asignacion.save returns false, that is to say, the validations fail, the "render new" doesn't work properly, and the page gives me the error: `No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"asignacion_diets", :locale=>:es}, missing required keys: [:id]`

I have checked that @asignacion.user_id isn't nil, it is a number

The route corresponding to the new action is: `get '/alumnos/:id/asignar_dieta' => 'asignacion_diets#new', as: "asignar_dieta"`

Answer (score 1):

The issue with this line

```
render :new, id: @asignacion.user_id
```

here `@asignacion.user_id` will return nil reason being

```
@asignacion = AsignacionDiet.new(asignacion_params)
```

and if `@asignacion.save` fails that means `@asignacion = nil`

so here alternative you can do this only: -

```
render :new
```

recommendation =>  you should pass `user_id` inside hidden field with new form, so in that case if `@asignacion.save` fails then you would be able to render at new action with `id: params[:user_id]`

Comment: asignacion.save fails because it doesn't pass "Asignacion"'s validations, not because it's nil. I have printed asignacion.user_id just before the render line and it shows "4"

Comment: @JOSEMAFUEN i m not sure, but if its issue of id then you should pass user_id in hidden field with new form so that you could render back it to new action with that user id, hope you understand,

Comment: @JOSEMAFUEN in that case according to your routes you can set hidden field value with user id = params[:id], as you are sending id with new action's routes, that is equivalent to user id, . am i clear to you?

Comment: @JOSEMAFUEN even if you will get asignacion.user_id just before the render and in that case if you will render to new action it will not get any user with id =4, because with there are no user saved in database with id =4 and in that case you will get more error at view page as well as new action, hopefully i'm clear to you. anyway feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you. :)